# How to add horizontal annotation line with short vertical ends in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Please forgive if my question is very basic. So I created this plot with:

```
library(ggpubr)
df <- data.frame("prop" = c(102.73,260.65), "Name" = c("All Genes","RG Genes"))
my_comparisons <- list(c("All Genes","RG Genes"))

p <-ggbarplot(df, x="Name", y="prop",fill="Name",legend ="",color = "white",palette = "jco",xlab = FALSE,ylab="cis eqtl per gene")

p + annotate("text", x = 1.5, y = 280, label = "p = 0.00578", size = 3.5) + annotate("rect", xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = 270, ymax =270, alpha=1,colour = "black")+ geom_vline(xintercept = 1:2)
```

The problems is that this plot doesn't look good. I would need this vertical lines around p value to be short, and not to go above the horizontal line, just a little bit bellow horizontal line.

Comment: Is that from `library(ggpubr)`?

Comment: It sounds like you want segments that connect the text to the bars. Something like this?  `+ annotate("segment", x = 1, xend = 1, y = 102, yend = 280) +
  annotate("segment", x = 1, xend = 1.2, y = 280, yend = 280) +
  annotate("segment", x = 1.8, xend = 2, y = 280, yend = 280) +
  annotate("segment", x = 2, xend = 2, y = 280, yend = 260)`

Comment: I just need to add this p = 0.00578 to my plot above teh horizontal like which has tails. Doesn't need to be exactly this code, it can be any that gives me that result. Yes it is library(ggpubr)